# Error when running Naive Bayes using DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, algorithm, size

I'm running a naive Bayes algorithm (package e1071) after processing text using tm package, all is working fine until I write:

```
refi_classifier <- naiveBayes(refi_train_fin, refi_train$DEFAULT)
```

when this message comes up:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x) :    cannot coerce class
>   "c("DocumentTermMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")" to a data.frame

refi_train_fin is a vector with less than 900 rows, each cell containing text

Is this a size issue?